# Ошибка в sequelize при создании базы данных: Dialect needs to be explicitly supplied as of v4.0.0

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

При создании базы данных sequelize выдает ошибку:

Error: Dialect needs to be explicitly supplied as of v4.0.0
    at new Sequelize (D:\tutorial\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:181:13)
    at Object. (D:\tutorial\util\database.js:3:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object. (D:\tutorial\app.js:9:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)

Диалект задан:

```
    const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize('node_complete', 'root', 'Kornienko130', 'nodecomplete', {
dialect: 'mysql',
host: 'localhost',
});

module.exports = sequelize;
```

Answer (score 0):

Суть ошибки в том, что у тебя не указана база данных, которую ты собрался использовать.
Вот тут детальнее о простейшей настройке: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/installation/getting-started

Обрати внимание на:

> dialect: 'mysql'|'sqlite'|'postgres'|'mssql',

index.js

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  config.db.database,
  config.db.username,
  config.db.password,
  config.db.options,
);
```

config.js

```
db: {
  database: 'localhost',
  username: 'root',
  password: 'root',
  options: {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'mysql',
    define: {
      engine: 'MyISAM',
      charset: 'utf8',
      collate: 'utf8_general_ci',
      timestamps: true,
    },
  },
}
```

У меня не был объявлен dialect после объявления все заработало.